# ListView.setChoiceMode and custom list item

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock

In a `SherlockListFragment` I'm using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` to display a single line of text. I'm using the following to get the `ListView` to automatically highlight the list item when selected...

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

This works fine.

However, I have another `SherlockListFragment` which uses a list item layout with two `TextView` widgets as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gl_item_single_start_time_short"
        ...
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/gl_item_single_title"
        ...
        >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I'd like to do is have the second `TextView`  (`gl_item_single_title`) automatically highlighted when the list item is selected.

The question is - what do I have to do to make this happen? Is there an attribute I can set on that `TextView` or do I have to handle this myself for the view returned by the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 to display a single line of text.

I assume that you meant that you are using your own layout copied from `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1`, since [that resource only exists on API Level 11+](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#simple_list_item_activated_1).

> What I'd like to do is have the second TextView (gl_item_single_title) automatically highlighted when the list item is selected.

I assume that you mean that you want it to behave as `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` does, with the persistent highlight for your selection.

> what do I have to do to make this happen?

Copy `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2` and modify to suit. Or, use `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` on some other layout. Note, though, that this only works on API Level 11+.

If you want something that works for all API levels, though:

First, extend your app's theme with one, in a `res/values-v11/` directory, that defines some new style (e.g., `activated`):

```
<style name="activated" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
</style>
```

Then, in `res/values/`, define that same style to be a no-op:

```
<style name="activated">
</style>
```

Finally, apply that style to your row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="2dip"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  style="@style/activated"
>
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:paddingRight="4dip"
  />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:textSize="5mm"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "I assume that you meant that you are using your own layout..." - No, that's part of the problem. At the moment this is just a "proof of concept" - I have a handful of testers and all are using devices with API Level 11 or later but I eventually want to support back to API 8 but haven't yet got around to copying the layout files to modify them to allow that. I'm basically just trying to understand the mechanisms first. Many thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Squonk: In that case, just try `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2` -- if it looks suitable for short-term use, it should "just work" from an "activated" standpoint.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I think `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2` will work short-term for demo purposes.